# Affordable combined Ruby/Rails/Redmine + Subversion hosting?

Tags: hosting, svn, web-hosting, ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am looking for a reliable hosting company I can entrust my code to in the form of a number of Subversion repositories, and a copy of the [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) project management tool. I am looking for something I can pay up front for a year or two, and is not too pricey.

I don't care where the company is located, as long as it's trustworthy and solid.

Does anybody know good recommendations? Preferably from own, personal, good experience.

I have looked at [CVSDude / Codesion](http://codesion.com) and while they are certainly great, they don't offer Redmine of course, and seem to be aiming toward bigger organizations mainly.

What I would need:

- 2-5 Gigs of space minimum, freely distributable between SVN, and Redmine attachments
- Unlimited number of Subversion projects
- Access control (team members / checkout-only accounts / etc.) I don't mind configuring the svn settings on file basis myself
- I need the possibility to map a custom domain to the package that is hosted elsewhere
- Frequent backups and access to those backups through FTP or other means

I have been running my own virtual server for this until now, but I don't want the hassle, especially on the security side, while I may not always have the internet connection to fix problems that may come up.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are accustomed to administering your own virtual server and want root access, Joyent is probably the host that you're looking for.  They specialize in hosting for Rails projects, including some of the larger ones, e.g. Twitter was on Joyent until 2008.

I pay $200/year for their bottom-of-the-line Accelerator (looks like there's a $25/month option now too), and I think you would find that it would accomplish everything that you're looking for:

- Root access to install gems/etc.
- 5GB storage (add 10GB more for $15/year)
- 10TB transfer per month (plenty for your SFTP backups)

The server comes pre-configured with Webmin/Virtualmin to simplify setting up domains, Subversion repositories, MySQL databases, etc., but you have full access to the command line as well.

Note that Joyent uses Solaris, not Linux, so there is a bit of a learning curve.  However, there's plenty of documentation and it's really not that big a deal.

(For readers other than the OP: I would not recommend this option for someone who does not have or want to develop the skills to set things up independently; there are other providers that offer more hands-on support, although they generally do not provide root access.)

Comment: p.s. of course, you'd have to install your own instance of Redmine on your Joyent Accelerator, but it sounds like you're fully competent to do that.

Comment: cheers, this sounds very interesting and affordable! Solaris would indeed be a bit of a learning curve but it could be worth it. Will definitely take a look.

Comment: @Pekka Thanks, let me know what you think. I like them a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with [ProjectLocker](http://www.projectlocker.com) and we host Subversion or Git and Trac.  Redmine's feature set is based largely on Trac, so unless there are specific plugins or Redmine-only features you're looking for, you may find that Trac meets your project management needs.

We currently offer plans with the size, project, and access control needs you're looking for for as little as $12/month or $119/year.  In addition to the disaster recovery backups taken multiple times daily and included in your subscription, you can also purchase a backup subscription that allows downloadable backups to be made available to you on a schedule automatically.  The ProjectLocker Portal interface allows you to manage users, projects, and Subversion access control through the Web, so there's no need to log in and configure any server functions.  Finally, we offer remote deployment, so you can deploy to your test or production environments from your repository at will.

We encourage you to give us a try; we have a 30 day money back guarantee and an unlimited free trial of 3 users and 3 projects to allow you to try some of the basic features.  We welcome any feedback you have for us as well, positive or negative, that will make us a better service for users like you that want Subversion hosting with full control and no hassle.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for Linux based with the option to have it managed there is Logicworks.
They have a Developer Utility Server currently in beta.
http://www.utility.noc.logicworks.net

Answer (score -1):

HI Pekka! I'm kind of new using these technologies. But hope I can be of any help anyway. I'm using Assembla (www.assembla.com) which is not pricey at all, in fact since I have only small projects I'm using Free SVN hosting ( It's not a public project so  it was hard to find a service that provides free svn hosting for private projects :) Good for me!! )